# Estou com um problema ao tentar usar um incremento na função printf - C

Tags: c, printf

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender porque a saída desse código é: 24 23 e não 23 23 ???

```
int a =23;

printf("%d %d",a, a++);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
}

Comment: Efeito colateral previsto. Pesquise por sequence point em http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/.

Comment: não se deve usar esse tipo de código, como foi dito na resposta abaixo é indefnida a ordem de avaliação dos parâmetros para uma função

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O padrão da linguagem C não estabelece qual a ordem de avaliação dos parâmetros de uma função. Logo, de acordo com o padrão da linguagem o seu código tem comportamento indefinido. 
A ordem de avaliação vai depender de cada compilador.

Nesse caso, fica claro que o compilador escolheu que o `a++` será avaliado antes do `a`.

Como a linguagem C não te dá garantia alguma sobre quem será avaliado primeiro nesse tipo de situação, aconselho evitar esse tipo de coisa em um código profissional.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda